What has been considered the correct response when one country is maliciously harming another economically?
Are there any precedents for the appropriate response if Country A is maliciously damaging Country B's economy, such as by counterfeiting Country B's currency?

This is going to depend on who country A and country B are and what exactly is going to happen. If country A is a large superpower and country B is a small nation without much power the reaction is going to be different then if the situation is reversed.

How did this post get a downvote?

Not my DV, but I think there's no pre-agreed 'proper' response. These days countries would often fight such an affair with some kind of [economic] sanctions, official or less so. Or at least some diplomatic rebuke, although pairs of countries that would be in such a position often don't have official diplomatic relations, at the outset.

@Grapefruit Not my downvote, but 1 sentence questions don't usually do well here.

There's no pre-agreed 'proper' response, e.g. spelled out in some multilateral treaty, that I know of.
These days countries would often fight such an affair with some kind of [economic] sanctions, official or less so. Or at least some diplomatic rebuke, although pairs of countries that would be in such a position often don't have official diplomatic relations (with each other), at the outset.
As a point of interest, during some past wars belligerent countries did counterfeit each other's currency. And in fact, even in between wars, which at some point in the 1930s was deemed too much, so an international treaty was adopted, formally banning the practice. As Wikipedia recounts:

In December 1925 a high-profile counterfeit scandal came to light, when three people were arrested in the Netherlands while attempting to disseminate forged French 1000-franc bills which had been produced in Hungary. Subsequent investigations uncovered evidence that plot had received widespread support in Hungarian and German nationalist circles including the patronage of high ranking military and civilian officials. Twenty-four of the conspirators were tried in Budapest in May 1926. Most received light sentences in what is believed to have been a deliberate cover up by Hungarian Prime Minister István Bethlen. The affair facilitated the adoption of the International Convention for the Suppression of Counterfeiting Currency in April 1929 and formalized the role of the International Criminal Police Commission.

OTOH, there aren't that many signatories of the International Convention for the Suppression of Counterfeiting Currency. Only about 83 countries signed up. And some big countries have signed but still not ratified it:

China, India, Japan, and the United States are among the states that have signed the treaty but have not ratified it.

Perusing the protocol that accompanied the treaty (or rather what exceptions countries have registered to it), signatories can bring case against each other at the ICJ in case of violation. So, for the signatories, or at least for the ratifiers, that would perhaps be a proper action, although the treaty doesn't bar other countermeasures. I'm not aware of any such counterfeiting cases (at  the ICJ). A number of signatory countries have also formally registered an exception to ICJ jurisdiction on this treaty. And, like I said, the majority of countries are not even signatories.

It's widely claimed that Iran or North Korea is printing "superdollars": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdollar

@pjc50: IIRC it was one of the (stated?) reasons why the US transitioned to a new $100 bill. I guess we can add that to the list of possible countermeasures, although it's not exactly cheap to keep doing that...
